# check value of json response in bash script

Tags: json, bash, shell, grep

```
{"running": 1, "finished": 3, "node_name": "L-2.local", "pending": 0, "status": "ok"}
```

I'm trying to parse this response to check the value of "running" with a bash script. I know there's libraries to do this, but some reason the jq library wouldn't install, and I prefer not to install it, as I only need it for this one command. Normally I'd use Python instead.

I tried using this command from another answer, on the response

`| grep -Po '"running":"\K[^,]*'`

but it failed due to the "."

`bash: {"running": 0, "finished": 0, "node_name": "L-2: command not found`

Is there a way to get it to check the value of "running" with grep, and not have the error?

Comment: You have a `"` in the pattern after `:`, but there is no quote in the string. Use `echo '...string...' | grep -Po '"running":\s*\K[^,]+'`. If you are sure there are digits only, use `'"running":\s*\K\d+'`

Comment: Thanks, I meant to add the version without the quote. I now discovered the -P option doesn't work with OSX, so can't get it to work yet.

Comment: You may use `sed` to get the value, though it won't look pretty. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sed` to remove what you do not need and only capture and keep what you need using a capturing group and a backreference:

```
s='{"running": 1, "finished": 3, "node_name": "L-2.local", "pending": 0, "status": "ok"}'
echo $s | sed 's/.*"running":[[:space:]]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kEqm7z).

**Pattern details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `"running":` - a literal substring
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\([0-9]*\)` - a capturing group (note the escapes, they are necessary since the pattern is POSIX BRE compliant) matching 0 or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

The `\1` is the backreference to the Group 1 value.

Answer (score 3):

First, this error `bash: {"running": 0, "finished": 0, "node_name": "L-2: command not found` is because you don't use echo before your expression.

use : `echo '{"running": 1, "finished": 3, "node_name": "L-2.local", "pending": 0, "status": "ok"}' | grep -Po '"running":\s*\K\d+'`